# When do I use 着 to indicate action in progress?

Tags: grammar, usage

It seems like for some verbs (正)在 is used to indicate action in progress, but I have also encountered 着 for some, like 穿着. When should it be used, is there a rule to follow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is used for both actions in progress and things that are happening in present tense, such as "she is wearing a dress".

I sometimes equate this to the -ing suffix.

Examples:

> 他穿**着**西装弹吉他

He (She) is wear**ing** a suit and playing guitar

> 你帮我看**着**他

Help me look out for him (her) **(at this moment)**

> 你看他扛**着**那么大的一个东西

See him carry**ing** such a big thing

However, this is not used as -ing with actions as you would expect:

This is wrong:

> <strike>他在游泳着</strike>

The 着 here should be applied to the 游 i.e.

> 他在游着

Wrong:

> <strike>他在弹吉他着</strike>

Right:

> 他在弹着吉他

Comment: 他正弹着吉他 is better than 他在弹着吉他, though I can't say 他在弹着吉他 is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

着 when used between two verbs signifies that the first action accompanies the second (main) action.

> 我喜欢躺着听音乐。
> I like to listen to music lying down
>
> 他坐着看电视。
> He sits watching television

Comment: I agree. Like an adverb.

Answer (score 2):

1. Indicating action in progress.

   As shown by @xiaohouzi79's answer.
2. Accompanying another major action.

   As shown by @trideceth12's answer.
3. Special usage

   Sometimes, neither of the above two can tell the whole story. For example,

   `走着瞧 (zǒu zhe qiáo) which roughly means Let's wait and see.`

   `你看着办吧 (nǐ kàn zhe bàn ba) which roughly means It's up to you.`

   You can say it falls to case 1 in some sense. But I feel it's used as a whole, like an idiom.